# rails s error libpq.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, 64-bit, libraries, pg

I am getting the subject error.

It seems the error has something to do with the postgres libraries not being 64 bit, but other than that I can't figure it out. Bundle install runs alright, but when I run rails s, I get:

```
jim@MJTPUB:~/rails/apps/apoxeia$ rails s
/home/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails328/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require':
libpq.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 - /home/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails328
/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError) 
from /home/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails328/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in 
`<top (required)>'
```

Where do I start to figure this out?

Thanks
- Jim

Comment: On what operating system and version? (Linux of some flavour, but ... detials?). With what PostgreSQL version? How did you install PostgreSQL and from where? How did you install Ruby, Rails and the Pg gem and from where? There's nowhere near enough detail here. Please edit your question to provide a lot more detail (see "asking better questions" on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info) and comment here when you've done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by your linker being unable to link the libraries together because one is 32-bit and one is 64-bit.  The fix is simple:  Make sure you have installed all the appropriate pieces on the same architecture (standardize on 32-bit or 64-bit).  If that fails, then check your build environment and see what it is targetting.

If that fails it may be a problem with your build environment, or the make files of the bundle or any number of other things.  You will need to take a close look at these things (and possibly provide a lot more information).